# How to click on button which is present in a frame using python selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, frame

I want to click on the shaded button but it's inside the frame, which seems to be inside another frame. How can I do it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT19V.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go into nested iframes and then click the button with text Continuar.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(ec.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//frame[@name='reloj']" )))
wait.until(ec.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//frame[@name='transicion']")))
wait.until(ec.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Continuar']"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```